# Non responsive submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, submit

I have written a submit_tag in my games/show.html.erb class and it is as followed:

```
 <% form_tag game_path, :method => 'submit' do %>
      <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Interested in trading", :name => 'confirm' %></div>
 <% end %>
```

In my `games_controller` under the `show` method I have the following:

```
def show
 @game = Game.find(params[:id])


 if params['confirm']
   respond_to do |format|
     user = @game.user
     email = user.email
     g = GameTrade.game_interest(user)
     g.deliver
     format.html { redirect_to root_url }
     format.json { render json: @game }
   end
 elsif
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
   end
 end
end
```

Now the show page displays fine but when I click on the `submit_tag` it does nothing and by nothing I mean it is dead you click on it and it does no action what so ever. Just a dummy. Any ideas what is wrong in my controller logic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your view, not your controller.

Submit tags must be inside forms. When you click on it, they submit the form -- without a containing form, the submit tag is totally useless.

If you want just a button that leads to somewhere, try checking out [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to): it will create a submit tag and a form directed towards whatever action you specify.

Comment: I see. So the above statement would be encased in a form. Would it be a simple <% form_tag do %> ..... <% end %> or is there greater logic to it than that?

Comment: Hey, I have updated my post above to what I have wrote (not sure if it is correct as I am going on my knowledge) but now the button has completely disappeared.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the right syntax. You want: ```<%= form_tag ... %>```. Make sure to get the equals sign in there or none of the output will appear in the view.